# Azure Disaster Recovery For App Service Plan and Application Insights

Tags: azure

Is it possible to make **DR for App Service Plan and Application Insights**
in Azure. Bellow link saying DR is not possible Application Insights but it's an old one. IF not possible let me know

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights/suggestions/35067769-failover-for-application-insight-as-part-of-disast

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/architecture-center/issues/1265